# CSS settings for boxes

Tags: html, css

I try to find a solution for a few hours now but I do not know how to do this. It is maybe a simple thing and I hope someone can help me out.

I created three boxes. Those boxes have a border at the top and change their background colours as soon as you scroll over with your mouse.

Screenshot without hover effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXAPs.png

Screenshot with hover effect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOcJ5.png

My problem is now, that I also need the colour of the title and the text in another colour (#ffffff)! I do not know how I have to change my .css!

Here is what I did:

```
.frontpage-box {
    position: relative !important;
    border-top: 8px solid #233c5b !important;
    background: #eeeff1 !important;
    height: 280px !important;
}


.frontpage-box:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative !important;
    border-top: 8px solid #daaf36 !important;
    background: #233c5b !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong? How do I have to change the code, so that the font color will be "white" after hover.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Where is the non-hover color set? Does that have !important on it as well?

Comment: using `!important`, especially this many times is a sign of bad css design. css is supposed to be cascading by default. in this case you are overriding the behavior.

Comment: if you provide a jsfiddle with your code example, that would help a lot.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `hover` styles.  There must be another style that's overriding them.  See http://jsfiddle.net/puz5avg6/  Please share more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code you would want to do

```
.frontpage-box:hover p { color: #fff }
```

and not set it in .frontpage-box:hover with the important.